# How to unit test Firebase (ios) properly?

Tags: ios, unit-testing, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm a bit stuck how to test my approach of saving and migrating data.  I have created a second Firebase project for my unit tests (even though this isn't ideal).

This is one of my tests:

```
func testMigratenOfFiveEvents() {
        var done = false
        let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
        createFTEvents(amount: 5)
        let events = MockDatastore.shared.eventsForLife()
        FIRUtil.migrateEventsToFirebase(ftevents: events!)
        let userRecords = ref.child("ft-records").child("test@gmail_com")
        userRecords.queryOrdered(byChild: "time").observe(FIRDataEventType.value, with: { snapshot in
            var i = 0
            for item in snapshot.children {
                i = i + 1
                let event = Event(snapshot: item as! FIRDataSnapshot)
                XCTAssertEqual(event.notes, "hello" + String(i))
            }
            done = true
        })
        waitUntil(timeout: 5, predicate: {done})
    }

    func waitUntil(timeout: TimeInterval, predicate:((Void) -> Bool)) {
        let timeoutTime = NSDate(timeIntervalSinceNow: timeout).timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate

        while (!predicate() && NSDate.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate < timeoutTime) {
            RunLoop.current.run(mode: RunLoopMode.defaultRunLoopMode, before: NSDate(timeIntervalSinceNow: 0.25) as Date)
        }
        if (!predicate() && NSDate.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate > timeoutTime) {
            XCTAssert(false, "Timeout - Couldn't connect to firebase database")
        }
    }
```

It waits 5 seconds to execute the test and does the assert accordingly. It works well when the laptop is connected to the internet.  But if it isn't I get a timeout exception.

This surprises me because in the Appdelete I have the following entry:

```
FIRDatabase.database().persistenceEnabled = true
```

According to the docs, this should have worked:

> Firebase apps remain responsive even when offline because the Firebase
>   Realtime Database SDK persists your data to disk. Once connectivity is
>   reestablished, the client device receives any changes it missed,
>   synchronizing it with the current server state.

Comment: Hi, did you get any solid working solution for this?

Comment: Sadly, no, I didn't find any solution.

Comment: I found Firebase emulators https://firebase.google.com/docs/emulator-suite But, it seems like an overkill for just unit tests, ideally the classes should be at least extended to allow mocking.